# How to loop dictionary with nested dictionaries

Tags: ansible

from the json below I need to gather the interface name and the unit name value in a loop.
This is partial output of my json:

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "@": {
            "junos:changed-localtime": "2021-04-30 12:47:05 PDT",
            "junos:changed-seconds": "1619812025",
            "xmlns": "http://xml.juniper.net/xnm/1.1/xnm"
        },
        "interfaces": {
            "interface": [
                {
                    "name": "irb",
                    "unit": [
                        {
                            "family": {
                                "inet": {
                                    "address": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "100.111.10.4/24"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "mtu": 9100
                                }
                            },
                            "name": 4010
                        },
                        {
                            "family": {
                                "inet": {
                                    "address": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "100.127.9.2/31"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "name": 4093
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "lo0",
                    "unit": [
                        {
                            "family": {
                                "inet": {
                                    "address": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "100.127.0.32/32"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    
                                }
                            },
                            "name": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The playbook I'm using is below:

```
- name: Print response
  debug:
    msg: "{{item.name}}.{{item|json_query('unit[*].name')}}"
  loop: "{{ test.parsed_output.configuration.interfaces.interface}}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

The problem that I'm having is this:

```
"msg": "lo0.[0]"
"msg": "irb.[4010, 4093]"
```

What I want to get is:

```
"msg": "lo0.0"
"msg": "irb.4010"
"msg": "irb.4093"
```

Same outside name with each unit.name, but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate [with_subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.name }} {{ item.1.name }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ test.parsed_output.configuration.interfaces.interface }}"
        - unit
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: irb 4010
  msg: irb 4093
  msg: lo0 0
```

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Botka, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Hello @Vladimir, how can I do the same, but if in the same json, I have some items with unit{} instead of unit [] ?

Comment: fatal: [device1: FAILED! => {"msg": "the key unit should point to a list, got '{'name': '0', 'family': {'inet': {'filter': {'input': {'filter-name': 'RESTRICT_ACCESS'}}, 'address': {'name': '100.127.0.32/32'}}}}'"}